# Sync new version with FTP to server?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, synchronization

I'm having problems updating a new version of a project to the remote web server.
The project contains about 500 MB of data (mostly graphics and javascript libraries that don't change very often). Currently I do this with WS-FTP with the sync option, but this is very slow, since it has to compare every local file with the remote one, to see if anything has changed.

I use SVN on my local server for version control. Would you use SVN on a production server too?  Or are there other kind of protocols that allow fast updates when only a few files have changed?

I use Eclipse (on Windows), so maybe there's a plugin that can keep track of all the changed files and use FTP to deploy them??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/).

A trivial search shows that it has [an Eclipse plugin](http://rsyncplugin.sourceforge.net/), too.

Answer (score 0):

I use Subversion in production environments too. As long as you modify your server settings to not allow .svn metadata to be served, you should be fine. Also, keeping development and production configurations separate and using tags helps keep thing clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with Subversion, go with it. I wouldn't run a Subversion server on that machine :) but I'd definitely be happy with `ssh website@remotehost svn pull`.

`rsync(1)` is the usual answer; it is an excellent program, and pretty easy to use:

```
rsync -avc -P /path/to/web/content/ website@remotehost:/path/to/content/
```

Comment: I develop on a Windows machine. Is rsync available for Windows too?  (With Google I find all kinds of scary Cygwin solutions)

Comment: @Dylan, there are [windows binaries for rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/download.html), in case you don't want to compile it yourself. I've used a Windows build of rsync on my father's windows machine before with great success (it replaced a _much_ slower recursive FTP copy operation to back up all his photos), but I don't know for certain that the linked windows build was the exact one I used or not.